# Top n Count per category in Sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a table looking like:

```
user    books
a       aa
a       ab
a       ab
a       ac
a       ac
a       ac
b       aa
b       aa 
b       aa
b       ac
c       aa
c       aa
c       ab
c       ab
c       ab
```

I want an aggregated fields that has the count fo unique books per user - and I want to show the top 2 of them, in a descending order, meaning:

```
user    book    count  
a       ac      3
a       ab      2 
b       aa      3
b       ac      1
c       ab      3  
c       aa      2
```

I'm using sqlite.

In postgres I would you over partition by, but I don't think there's an equivalent in sqllite.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select user, book, count(*) cnt
From t a
Where book in (
  Select book
  From t b
  Where a.user = b.user
  Group by book
  Order by count(*) desc
  Limit 2
)
Group by user, book;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a real pain in SQLite, because it has neither variables nor window functions.  One method is a correlated subquery:

```
with ub as (
      select user, book, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by user, book
     )
select ub.*
from ub
where ub.book in (select ub2.book
                  from ub ub2
                  where ub2.user = ub.user
                  order by cnt desc
                  limit 2
                 );
```

Note:  If there are ties, this arbitrary picks two of them.

Comment: this doesn't work when plugged in the query object in: https://github.com/yhat/pandasql